# Why the result of my ASP.NET Core API is cached?

Tags: caching, asp.net-core

This is so frustrating. The result of an API should not be cached, unless we explicitly say so.

However, on this server, on this particular instance of my deployment the result gets cached. And it's so annoying and causes a huge amount of bugs.

Here's the API endpoint example:

```
http://example.com/user/list
```

And Google Chrome keeps showing `(from disk cache)`. I checked, and there isn't any caching header available anywhere for this request, and the point is that we have more than 10 servers and more than 50 instances of our API deployed and only here it gets this stupid behavior. What can be wrong and where should I check?

Update: Response headers are:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
Date: Sun, 30 Sep 2018 05:20:36 GMT
Content-Length: 355
```

Comment: GET requests are cached by browsers by default. If you want to prevent that, then you will need to add cache headers that explicitly prevent caching.

Comment: @poke, thanks for answering. But you didn't consider the fact that this happens only on one server, and for a lot more `GET` requests on other applications we don't get the same behavior out of the box, without explicitly preventing caching.

Comment: So you have the same application deployed on multiple machines and you only see this on one of them? Then you should figure out what the difference between your servers is. – In general, if you compare the response headers from your API and they are the same, then there's nothing wrong with your server application and the behavior should be identical.